# Вызов alert или отправка cookie с помощью $()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть такой код:

```
var fragment = 'test';
$('.open .close-' + fragment).closest('.open').addClass('close-extbl');
```

Что мне подставить в `fragment` чтобы вызвать `alert`? Или куки отправить на хост?

Пытаюсь понять уязвимость, которую допустил.

Comment: если fragment это строка - то ничего. строка переданная в `$()` **НЕ** выполняется

Comment: в оригинале fragment это document.location.hash

Comment: без разницы, это все еще обычная строка

Comment: @Grundy, хм, это только в `$()` работает так? просто данные из `input` тоже текст, но при этом многие xss через input и эксплуатируются

Comment: по сути, не важно откуда приходит строка, важно, что с ней происходит дальше

Comment: @Grundy а как же `eval(document.location.hash.split('#')[1])` ?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, а в вопросе нет `eval` :P

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Вот об этом и говорит@Grundy. Пока она передается в jquery как селектор все ок. Как только ее где то берет eval - все начинает быть не очень :)

Comment: @МолюскаМоллюсков А почему вы решили что есть уязвимость?

Comment: @Vitalii я допустил это, ничего не решил, спасибо за помощь